# Aren't egrep, fgrep supposed to be aliases to grep?

Tags: grep, symbolic-link, alias

Since egrep is essentially grep -E I would expect it to be an alias that calls grep with that option. However on my system

```
file `which egrep`
```

shows it is an executable. Also egrep as an alias only invokes `egrep` with the color option. Why is it not an alias? Do they compile a separate binary for egrep?

Just curious...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the OS and the version of the grep tools installed.

Some examples for systems I happen to have access to:

- Ubuntu 11.04, GNU grep 2.6.3: /bin/grep, /bin/fgrep, and /bin/egrep are three distinct executable files with different sizes.
- GNU grep 2.10 (just released a few days ago), built from source: the same.
- Cygwin: the same.
- CentOS 5.6 (a clone of Red Hat), GNU grep 2.5.1: /bin/egrep and /bin/fgrep are symlinks to /bin/grep.
- GNU grep 2.5.1 built from source: egrep and fgrep are small shell scripts that invoke grep.
- Solaris 9: three different files (Solaris tools, not GNU).

Answer (score 1):

They used to be separate executables, but these days it's usually a single executable with three hard links ("grep", "fgrep" & "egrep") all pointing to the same program: the program checks which name it was started as, and behaves accordingly.

So what you're running is an enhanced egrep with the features of the other two programs included: and calling it by different names, or with *-E* gives you the features you expect.

If you type

```
ls -i `which grep`
```

and the same for **fgrep** and **egrep** you may see that they all have the same inode number, which means they are all the same file.

Comment: Well at least on my system they have different inode number (off by 3). but in principle I understand your point. they could be hard symlinks and the grep program could look up argv[0] to find out what options to apply.

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu 18.04 `cat /bin/egrep` outputs

```
    #!/bin/sh 
    exec grep -E "$@"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).